# Limit on matrix size in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to create a large matrix(for example, Mat_(300000,300000)) whose size exceeds the range of SIZE_T, and it seems that this will cause an error in run time. Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: imho, you can't. Mat's internal members are all signed int, and the total() number of elems has to fit into an int, too.

Comment: Here the feature for OpenCV http://code.opencv.org/issues/2298 . It was canceled, but contains advise to use.